# Yahoo OAuth with ASP.NET giving error 502

Tags: asp.net, authentication, oauth, yahoo

I followed this tutorial: https://www.learnmvc.in/aspnet-mvc-identity-with-yahoo-account.php

This is how I registered my app in developer.yahoo.com:

[image]

I installed Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo and added the following code in Startup.Auth:

```
app.UseYahooAuthentication(new YahooAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ConsumerKey = "",
    ConsumerSecret = ""
});
```

I Changed the Project url to: http://localhost:8000/

I was initially getting this error "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present." Then I commented the VerifyCode method of the AccountController and was no longer getting this error.

However I am getting a 502 internal server error.

[image]

I even tried putting 127.0.0.1 in the callback domain, but I am still getting the same error. How can I solve this?

Comment: I did this exact same thing 5 months ago and it was working great.  Now, same error  (Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (internal error - server connection terminated)).  If you find a solution, please post it here.

Comment: @DaveLucre any updates?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't checked and I've been advising my users to use User/Pass instead of Yahoo OAuth.  I will check again and report back.  Though I expect that since you're asking for an update I will find the same result.